# Getting Alembic Database Version Programmatically

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm trying to figure out how to get the version of my database using Alembic. I've already gotten the database set up to use alembic and successfully performed both an upgrade and downgrade on it. I now want to get this version from my own python script.

I attempted to create a function for doing this

```
def get_current_database_version():
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir)
    alembic_cfg = Config(os.path.join(path, 'alembic.ini'))
    current_rev = command.current(alembic_cfg, head_only=True)
    return current_rev
```

This function returned a `NoSectionError: No section: 'formatters'`

I then went to my alembic.ini file to check that it had a formatters area. This is my alembic.ini file:

```
# A generic, single database configuration.

[alembic]
# path to migration scripts
script_location = alembic
pyramid_config_file = ../../development.ini

# template used to generate migration files
# file_template = %%(rev)s_%%(slug)s

# max length of characters to apply to the
# "slug" field
#truncate_slug_length = 40

# set to 'true' to run the environment during
# the 'revision' command, regardless of autogenerate
# revision_environment = false

# set to 'true' to allow .pyc and .pyo files without
# a source .py file to be detected as revisions in the
# versions/ directory
# sourceless = false

sqlalchemy.url = sqlite:///%(here)s/mgo.sqlite


# Logging configuration
[loggers]
keys = root,sqlalchemy,alembic

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = WARN
handlers = console
qualname =

[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine

[logger_alembic]
level = INFO
handlers =
qualname = alembic

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s
datefmt = %H:%M:%S
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Edit:

Here is my attempt to use MigrationContext to solve the problem:

```
def get_database_revision():
    engine = create_engine("sqlite:///../mgo.db")
    conn = engine.connect()
    context = MigrationContext.configure(conn)
    current_rev = context.get_current_revision()
    return current_rev
```

It connects but returns none. Using sqlite browser I can see that the version in the database is not set to none.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `MigrationContext` to [get the current version](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/runtime.html#alembic.runtime.migration.MigrationContext):

```
from alembic.migration import MigrationContext
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("postgresql://mydatabase")
conn = engine.connect()

context = MigrationContext.configure(conn)
current_rev = context.get_current_revision()
```

Inside `env.py` you can use:

```
from alembic import context
migration_context = context.get_context()
current_rev = context.get_current_revision()
```

Lastly, it basically comes down to connecting to the database and looking at the `alembic_version`  table. It contains the migration version as a value and that's where the database currently is (according to alembic). So you can write the code any way you want as long as that's ultimately what you're doing.

Comment: I changed my code to try this and it didn't work either. It returns None.

Comment: Did you check whether you're properly connected to the database?

Comment: Note that in never versions of alembic `MigrationContext` is moved to `alembic.runtime.migration`

Answer (score 6):

I suggest using stdout Config() object parameter (see [here](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/config.html#alembic.config.Config)) to allow redirecting sys.stdout into a StringIO buffer as done here:

```
output_buffer = io.StringIO()
alembic_cfg = alembic_Config('/path/to/alembic.ini', stdout=output_buffer)
alembic_command.current(alembic_cfg)
output = output_buffer.getvalue()
print(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is old, but I have a solution which I think is a little simpler than those given so far.

The main observation is that when `command.current` is called, alembic doesn't use Python's built-in `print` function but instead uses the `print_stdout` method on the config object. Therefore, to capture the output just overload the `print_stdout` function! This works for me:

```
def get_current_database_version():
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir)
    alembic_cfg = Config(os.path.join(path, 'alembic.ini'))

    captured_text = None
    def print_stdout(text, *arg):
        nonlocal captured_text
        captured_text = text

    alembic_cfg.print_stdout = print_stdout
    command.current(alembic_cfg)
    return captured_text
```

Comment: I just want to point out that this works with other commands like:   
command.heads
and  command.history

Answer (score 2):

```
from alembic.config import Config
from alembic import command
from alembic.script import ScriptDirectory
from alembic.runtime.environment import EnvironmentContext


class DBMigrations:

    def __init__(self):
        self.alembic_cfg = Config("./alembic.ini")
        self.alembic_cfg.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', DATABASE_URL)
        self.script = ScriptDirectory.from_config(self.alembic_cfg)

    def get_db_version(self):
        current_version = ""

        def display_version(rev, context):
            for rev in self.script.get_all_current(rev):
                nonlocal current_version
                current_version = rev.cmd_format(verbose=False)
            return []

        with EnvironmentContext(self.alembic_cfg, self.script, fn=display_version, dont_mutate=True):
            self.script.run_env()
        return current_version.split()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to throw in my 2 cents.

Firstly, it could be that MigrationContext didn't work for you because you did not connect to the proper database.  From the documentation I have seen create_engine will create a db for you if it can't find the file you specified. This could have happened because in your example you were using a relative path which can be easily confused.

Secondly, what pained me most is that

```
command.current(alembic_cfg, head_only=True)
```

actually only *displays* the current version, which for me appears to be printing the value to the console in eclipse.  The function itself always returns None which is a little annoying and that is why MigrationContext is needed.

Furthermore, if you are checking current version because you want to know the state of the db without actually updating it then you will need to use ScriptDirectory http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/script.html#alembic.script.ScriptDirectory
and its various methods to figure out if the version returned by MigrationContext is the current head or if it is even valid at all.

Answer (score 1):

A hack! Using [`sh`](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/), in the correct directory, it's as easy as:

```
>>> from sh import alembic
>>> alembic("current")
4cad21a83709 (head)
```

Comment: Well, one could easily use subprocess in the same way, but I don't think that's what the question is about.

Comment: Depends how we (or the OP) are defining "programatically" of course! Should the term explicitly exclude calling another process?

Answer (score 1):

Just building on [James Fennel's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1527420/james-fennell) answer, in the case of getting the history it will just output one line.  If you want all of the output (as a list) you can do:

```
def get_current_database_history(input_cfg, start_rev=None):
    captured_text = []
    def print_stdout(text, *arg):
        nonlocal captured_text
        captured_text.append(text)
    input_cfg.print_stdout = print_stdout
    if start_rev:
        command.history(input_cfg, rev_range="{}:".format(start_rev))
    else:
        command.history(input_cfg)
    return captured_text
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a temporary fix that returns the correct version number.

```
def get_database_revision():
    s = select(['version_num'],from_obj='alembic_version')
    result = DBSession.execute(s).fetchone()
    return result['version_num']
```

This function returns None if no version number is found.

Comment: Nowadays we have to use this version of expression ```select([text('version_num')], from_obj=text('alembic_version'))```

Comment: Which module to import to get `select` ? :)

Answer (score 0):

I just read the DB for the alembic_version table:

```py
    try:
        version_num = db.execute("SELECT version_num FROM alembic_version").first()[0]
    except:
        version_num = None
```